# How to automount HPFS/NTFS (exFAT) 64GB microSD card on 10.04?

Tags: mount, ntfs, automount, exfat

When trying to mount my 64GB microSD card, it fails. Did a bit of research and found I needed exfat.

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:relan/exfat

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install fuse-exfat`

I can now mount the filesystem manually & everything works fine.
What am I now supposed to do to enable the automount?
Any insights or guidance as to what I can do would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by “automount”? Do want to mount the volume during boot or as soon as it's plugged it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in /etc/fstab this seems to work ok

/dev/sdb1   /media/sd        exfat-fuse    defaults,nobootwait,user

but it breaks normal automounting of any non-exfat SD card or USB thumbdrive
either there's a way to make it conditional on being an SD card I'm missing or we have to wait for an update in the normal automounting

Answer (score 1):

Since Ubuntu 11.04, exfat drives automount normally if fuse-exfat has been installed.